# SQL Server function return unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a function to check if user is authenticated but the result is not correct :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsAuthorized] 
    (@UserToken nvarchar(250), 
     @UserCode nvarchar(250))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT [User].UserId 
        FROM [User] 
        INNER JOIN UserLogin ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
        WHERE [User].UserCode = @UserCode 
          AND UserLogin.UserToken = @UserToken 
          AND UserLogin.UserTokenExpiration > GETDATE()) > 0
        RETURN 1;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [User].UserId 
                   FROM [User] 
                   WHERE [User].UserCode = @UserCode)
        RETURN -201;    -- User does not exist

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [User].UserId 
                   FROM [User] 
                   INNER JOIN UserLogin ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
                   WHERE [User].UserCode = @UserCode 
                     AND UserLogin.UserToken = @UserToken)
        RETURN -202;    -- Token is not valid

    IF EXISTS (SELECT [User].UserId 
               FROM [User] 
               INNER JOIN UserLogin ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
               WHERE [User].UserCode = @UserCode 
                 AND UserLogin.UserToken = @UserToken 
                 AND UserLogin.UserTokenExpiration < GETDATE())
        RETURN -203;    -- Token expired

    RETURN 0;
END
```

When I try to run:

```
DECLARE @UserCode nvarchar(250) = N'7C6898E2-0529-4C3F-B4B2-FA69087CDF4A';
DECLARE @UserToken nvarchar(250)= N'DE3B193D-65BC-4F75-970A-932C9F825D81';

SELECT dbo.IsAuthorized(@UserCode,@UserToken) as FunctionResult

SELECT *
FROM [User]
INNER JOIN UserLogin ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId
WHERE
    [User].UserCode = @UserCode
    AND UserLogin.UserToken = @UserToken
    AND UserLogin.UserTokenExpiration > GETDATE()
```

I get this result:

==> the function does not find the line

```
-201
```

==> the query finds a line

```
4   7C6898E2-0529-4C3F-B4B2-FA69087CDF4A    Ahmed   ALOUI   TROY    aloui.ahmed@wanadoo.fr  0       0   1   0   /Ressources/img/aloui.jpg   4   73828562FADE36DD6774C6854F52965C    CC6CA2373C2240743D051352BC3AF3C0    DE3B193D-65BC-4F75-970A-932C9F825D81    2016-11-25 16:02:12.083
```

Any clues?

Comment: I tried using EXISTS ... select count(*)... >0 but the problem is in the function because the query is correct and when I run it it returns the correct result

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in your function, you are running a `SELECT` and comparing the result of that select to see whether it is greater than zero, (which will not work), whereas in your raw `SELECT` without using the function, you are just returning the whole record(s) if found.

You probably want this in your function:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT([User].UserId)
        FROM [User] 
        INNER JOIN UserLogin ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
        WHERE [User].UserCode = @UserCode 
          AND UserLogin.UserToken = @UserToken 
          AND UserLogin.UserTokenExpiration > GETDATE()) > 0
        RETURN 1;
```

which will count the number of records returned by your `SELECT` and if the number is greater than zero, will return a value of 1 from the function.

Comment: Count would be the most appropriate however, as long as User.UserId is numeric and the query produced a single row (or a scalar value) comparing User.UserId > 0 with out count will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM
       User u
       INNER JOIN UserLogin l
       ON u.UserId = l.UserId
       AND l.UserToken = @UserTokey
       AND l.UserTokenExpiration = GETDATE()
    WHERE
       u.UserCode = @UserCode
)
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END
```

So the way you have User.UserId > 0 should work but only if a single scalar numeric value is returned from the query.  If multiple are returned it would error out.  Given what you are showing that would seem to be true but perhaps you are only showing some of the results etc.  Anyway, in the rest of the function you are using the perfect technique to change this too as well. Just use `IF EXISTS(SELECT....)`.

Note it is a pet peeve of mine to include conditions to restrict a joined table in the WHERE clause instead of the ON conditions.  putting them in the ON could be more optimized but your intentions are clearer as such I have modified the query to reflect that suggestion.